# Add a class to all next element until child with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a "bg-info" class using jQuery to all off the tr's that come after the odd tr's with a child > child class of "test". The "bg-info" class should stop being applied when a tr with a child > child class of "test" is seen and then continue being applied when the next odd tr with a child > child class of "test" seen. The amount is dynamic so it cannot rely on a specific number of tr's. I have tried many combination but can not seem to get this to work correctly. See JSFiddle. Thanks in advance :)

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/vrpuahue/4/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="test">Test1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="test">Test2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="test">Test3</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="test">Test4</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="test">Test5</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg-info {
  background: grey;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('tbody tr td .test:odd').parent().parent().addClass('bg-info');
```

Comment: I feel like there is a better way to explain this and show the example (for example in your fiddle instead of the text saying `example` it could say `this should be highlighted` / `this shouldn't`)

Comment: good idea will make that change

Comment: Is requirement to add `className` to `tr` element following odd `tr` element that contains element having `class` `.test` ?

Comment: Something like that ? https://jsfiddle.net/vrpuahue/8/  (I edited to make the tr containing .test class to not change)

Comment: Yes for the most part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method can help you in this situation.

I add a class to all the even and odd parents and then `highlight` the specific elements desired.

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mk6sw09f/)**

```js
$('.test:odd').parents('tr').addClass('odd');
$('.test:even').parents('tr').addClass('even');
$('.odd').nextUntil('.even').addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Test</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="test">Test1</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="test">Test2</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="test">Test3</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="test">Test4</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="test">Test5</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Do Not Highlight</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Simple solution I love it. I will test it out in my code and accept it if everything comes out good. Thanks.

Comment: Works great. Appreciate it. I do not know why I did not think of just adding classes. So simple. :)

Comment: @user262430 glad to help!